# I need Matcher<String> containsString(Matcher<String> matcher), am I doing something wrong?

Tags: java, hamcrest

I'd like to check that a string contains another string, ignoring case. Basically, I'd like to do this:

```
assertThat(dialogTitle.getText(), containsString(equalToIgnoringCase("Diagram")));
```

But I couldn't find a `Matcher<String>` that takes another `Matcher<T>`. Is there a different way how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also simply use:

```java
org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat
```

Usage:

```java
assertThat("Actual String", containsStringIgnoringCase("Expected Substring"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can implement your own matcher by extending `SubstringMatcher` from the `org.hamcrest.core` package:

```
public class StringContainsIgnoringCase extends SubstringMatcher {
    public StringContainsIgnoringCase(String substring) {
        super(substring);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean evalSubstringOf(String s) {
        return s.toLowerCase().contains(substring.toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override
    protected String relationship() {
        return "containing (ignoring case)";
    }

    public static Matcher<String> containsStringIgnoringCase(String substring) {
        return new StringContainsIgnoringCase(substring);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
assertThat(dialogTitle.getText(), StringContainsIgnoringCase.containsStringIgnoringCase("Diagram"));
```

And for readability you can make a static import of course and you get:

```
assertThat(dialogTitle.getText(), containsStringIgnoringCase("Diagram"));
```

---

The matcher you are asking for is already in the [master branch of the JavaHamcrest project](http://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/blob/master/hamcrest-core/src/main/java/org/hamcrest/core/StringContains.java) unfortunately it is not in the latest release of Hamcrest (1.3).